# Ajax not running php file

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I have created a PHP file which updates a value in a database.

I want to run this PHP file before the page that I call the file on loads. I have been using Ajax to do this but so far it hasn't been a success

```
<script type="text/javascript src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $.ajax(
    {
        post: "GET",
        url: "/wp-content/custom-php/MapMetricsApiCall.php"
    }).success(function() 
    {
        alert('worked');
    }).error(function() 
    {
        alert('didnt work');
    });
});
</script>

<?php
    echo get_option('totalDay');
    echo "<br/>";
    echo get_option('totalWeek');
    echo "<br/>";
    echo get_option('totalMonth');
    echo "<br/>";
    echo get_option('totalAmount');
?>
```

when the page loads it hits the success function but it hasn't been successful. I'm not sure if it is because it hasn't loaded the URL correctly but the values aren't been updated. I also want it to update the values before the page loads not when it has loaded

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){});` waits until the page loads...

Comment: If it hits the success function, it is successful. The problem with values not updating must lie elsewhere.

Comment: You've told us your values aren't updating, but you haven't put any code in the above that actually updates your values, so we've got no real way of helping you debug it.

Comment: @JamesHunt I know that the php file updates my database as I have added the php code to a page and when i refresh that page the values get updated, this means that it must be to do with my ajax request

Comment: @nerdlyist thanks for stating that but if I knew how to do it I wouldnt have made the mistake so maybe an answer might help

Comment: You had stated you wanted this to happen before the page loads which is counter to that call. Also, why not just do an include of that script? You are not passing anything in it looks like.

Comment: @nerdlyist I just used this instead and it works `<? require_once(ABSPATH. '/wp-content/custom-php/MapMetricsApiCall.php'); ?>`

Comment: Well if that because of what I said glad to help